# Python Pandas - Produce a sum total of a column that either has a value '1' in it or NaN

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
Opened              Closed              Resolved                   07:01 - 09:00    09:01 - 11:00   11:01 - 13:00   
2020-04-14 14:45:58 2020-04-14 15:04:22 0 days 00:18:24.000000000                                   1   
2020-04-14 13:43:28 2020-04-14 14:12:22 0 days 00:28:54.000000000                   1   
2020-04-14 13:41:18 2020-04-14 14:12:28 0 days 00:31:10.000000000                   1   
2020-04-14 10:57:53 2020-04-14 11:24:58 0 days 00:27:05.000000000       1           
2020-04-14 09:18:14 2020-04-14 09:44:04 0 days 00:25:50.000000000       1           
2020-04-14 09:16:28 2020-04-14 09:31:12 0 days 00:14:44.000000000       1           
2020-04-13 22:56:09 2020-04-14 00:39:30 0 days 01:43:21.000000000                   
2020-04-13 20:10:31 2020-04-13 20:26:25 0 days 00:15:54.000000000                   
2020-04-13 08:29:38 2020-04-13 18:29:25 0 days 09:59:47.000000000       1               
2020-04-09 14:04:14 2020-04-09 15:31:01 0 days 01:26:47.000000000                   1   
2020-04-09 10:06:24 2020-04-09 10:33:39 0 days 00:27:15.000000000       1           
2020-04-08 21:38:13 2020-04-09 07:01:30 0 days 09:23:17.000000000                   
2020-04-08 15:51:41 2020-04-08 16:08:02 0 days 00:16:21.000000000                                   1
2020-04-08 15:50:09 2020-04-08 16:07:57 0 days 00:17:48.000000000                                   1
2020-04-08 15:48:38 2020-04-08 16:07:52 0 days 00:19:14.000000000                                   1
```

I want to produce a sum of all the '1' values at the bottom of each column so it would look something like this.

```
Opened              Closed              Resolved                   07:01 - 09:00    09:01 - 11:00   11:01 - 13:00   
2020-04-14 14:45:58 2020-04-14 15:04:22 0 days 00:18:24.000000000                                   1   
2020-04-14 13:43:28 2020-04-14 14:12:22 0 days 00:28:54.000000000                   1   
2020-04-14 13:41:18 2020-04-14 14:12:28 0 days 00:31:10.000000000                   1   
2020-04-14 10:57:53 2020-04-14 11:24:58 0 days 00:27:05.000000000       1           
2020-04-14 09:18:14 2020-04-14 09:44:04 0 days 00:25:50.000000000       1           
2020-04-14 09:16:28 2020-04-14 09:31:12 0 days 00:14:44.000000000       1           
2020-04-13 22:56:09 2020-04-14 00:39:30 0 days 01:43:21.000000000                   
2020-04-13 20:10:31 2020-04-13 20:26:25 0 days 00:15:54.000000000                   
2020-04-13 08:29:38 2020-04-13 18:29:25 0 days 09:59:47.000000000       1               
2020-04-09 14:04:14 2020-04-09 15:31:01 0 days 01:26:47.000000000                   1   
2020-04-09 10:06:24 2020-04-09 10:33:39 0 days 00:27:15.000000000       1           
2020-04-08 21:38:13 2020-04-09 07:01:30 0 days 09:23:17.000000000                   
2020-04-08 15:51:41 2020-04-08 16:08:02 0 days 00:16:21.000000000                                   1
2020-04-08 15:50:09 2020-04-08 16:07:57 0 days 00:17:48.000000000                                   1
2020-04-08 15:48:38 2020-04-08 16:07:52 0 days 00:19:14.000000000                                   1

Total                                                                   5           3               4                 
12
```

So each column has itself summed up and then all columns have a total as well.

I tried

`data.groupby('Total')["07:01 - 09:00"].sum()[1]`

But that outputs a long string of '1' `11111111111`

How do I actually get a total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example you provided, probably your three (3) columns named ("07:01 - 09:00, 09:01 - 11:00, 11:01 - 13:00") are dtype: str, that's the reason you are getting a long string of 1's. Said that, you should cast your columns to float as follows:

```
data['07:01 - 09:00'] = data['07:01 - 09:00'].astype(float)
data['09:01 - 11:00'] = data['09:01 - 11:00'].astype(float)
data['11:01 - 13:00'] = data['11:01 - 13:00'].astype(float)
```

After that you could try the following:

```
data = data.append(data[['07:01 - 09:00', '09:01 - 11:00', '11:01 - 13:00']].sum(), 
                   ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''`

I assume it's because I have  empty values which I need to skip over or remove. How do I do that?

Comment: try this for all three columns:    
   
    data['07:01 - 09:00'] = data['07:01 - 09:00'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('',float(nan))

Comment: I get this error
  `File "<ipython-input-155-04170ca764e5>", line 1
    data['07:01 - 09:00'] = data['07:01 - 09:00'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('',float(nan))
                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: After adding the extra `)` i get
`name 'nan' is not defined`

Comment: Yes, sorry . It should be as follows data['07:01 - 09:00'] = data['07:01 - 09:00'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('',float('nan')))